# flexslider and flexcarousel on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexslider

When I try to use "basic flexlisder" (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html) and "basic carousel" (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html) on one page, carousel does not display properly. I guessed it's fault of clashing class names (since both are in `<div class="flexslider">`). However, after analyzing source code on flexslider page, I found they put the carousel in `<div class="flexslider carousel">` , unlike what is written in the example, but it still did not help. Carousel still behaves like slider.

I also tried copying styles for new class, which I called flexcarousel, but it didn't work (even after making changes in jquery call as well). Anyone has simple example of slider and carousel working on a simple page?

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    //slideshow
                    $(window).load(function() {
                        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                            animation : "slide",
                            start : function(slider) {
                                $('body').removeClass('loading');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    //carousel
                    $(window).load(function() {
                        $('.flexcarousel').flexslider({
                            animation : "slide",
                            animationLoop : false,
                            itemWidth : 210,
                            itemMargin : 5,
                            minItems : 2,
                            maxItems : 4
                        });
                    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel class does not actually make it a carousel, you have to assign the items a width using `itemWidth`, within the options:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,  // Must have a size set for it to switch to carousel view.
  });
});
```

Make sure to use different IDs to target each individual flexslider (if you have more than one):

```
<div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
<div id="secondary-slider" class="flexslider">
```

Comment: you can combine those two window loads into one, and use IDs for both like `#flex-slider` and `#flex-carousel`.

Comment: When I use "slide" for carousel along ZURB Foundation 5 I get the UL class' width set to 800% and not working result!